# Pass a CString as IStream*

Tags: c++

I need to pass a `CString` to a method but the method takes `Istream*` as the parameter I was wondering can someone tell me how to convert `CString` to `Istream*`.

Here's the method :

```
void ConvertToODF(Istream* spLetterToconvert);
```

Comment: It sounds like yo want to open an input file stream using the strings.

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way is to use [`SHCreateMemStream()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773831.aspx), eg:

```
CString str = ...;
IStream *strm = SHCreateMemStream((BYTE*)(LPCTSTR)str, str.GetLength() * sizeof(TCHAR));
if (strm)
{
    ConvertToODF(strm);
    strm->Release();
}
```

Depending on what character encoding `ConvertToODF()` is actually expecting, you may need to convert the content of the `CString` before then calling `SHCreateMemStream()`.